# Custom claims not returned by Azure ID to ASP.NET app using OpenId auth

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I am working on switching an existing ASP.NET 4.7.2 MVC web application that currently does single sign-on authentication against local ADFS to SSO authentication against Azure AD using OpenID.

We have several custom claims set up in Azure AD as shown below:
[image: Custom claims]

My implementation of the Startup class is as follows:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {           
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2)
        });

        SecurityKey key = null;
        try
        {
            var cert = new X509Certificate2(CERTIFICATE_FILE);
            key = new X509SecurityKey(cert);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error creating X509 security key from certificate file.", ex);
        }

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
            RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI,
            Authority = AUTHORITY,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = AUTHORITY,
                IssuerSigningKey = key
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived, 
                // etc...
            },
        });
    }
```

Users are getting authenticated alright, but when I check `arg.JwtSecurityToken.Claims` inside the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification arg)` method all I get are the standard claims:

- aud
- iss
- iat
- nbf
- exp
- aio
- c_hash
- name
- nonce
- oid
- preferred_username
- rh
- sub
- tid
- uti
- ver = 2.0

None of the custom claims appear in the collection, nor are they available in the `ClaimsPrincipal` instance in the controller classes.

However, they are being returned in the SAML response:

```
<AttributeStatement>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
        <AttributeValue>AMW</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
        <AttributeValue>SAD</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
        <AttributeValue>xyz@xyz.com</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
        <AttributeValue>xyz</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/department">
        <AttributeValue>590</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
</AttributeStatement>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please provide the `ClaimsPrincipal` code how you registered and added to `userIdentity`?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT, I cast the `User` property of the controller class as `ClaimsPrincipal` in my code. But the main issue is that the custom claims registered in Azure AD aren't being returned in the auth token, which is why they are also missing in `User`.